# JavaScript: Changing a texture on webgl globe with onclick event

Tags: javascript, webgl-globe

I'm using Google's webGL globe for a fun project of mine.

Want: When a user clicks a box with a "moon" icon it changes the image used
to make the globe from world.jpg to world_night.jpg.

There is a file that handles the texture element of the globe. here is the line of code responsible for getting the image location to wrap the globe with.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
sceneAtmosphere = new THREE.Scene();

var geometry = new THREE.Sphere(200, 40, 30);

shader = Shaders['earth'];
uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

*uniforms['texture'].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world' +
    '.jpg');*
```

The important line is within asterisks at the bottom.

I am using a simple function like this to change the texture

```
<style>
function nightTime() {
uniforms['texture'].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world_night' +
        '.jpg');
}
</style>
...filler html
<img src="moon.png" width="30px" onClick="nightTime()">
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Again when someone clicks the moon icon I need this

```
*uniforms['texture'].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world' +
        '.jpg');*
```

to change to this

```
*uniforms['texture'].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world_night' +
        '.jpg');*
```

*Note: The thing I am trying to change is in a file called globe.js.  The function is in an index.html file*

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

This: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
And this: http://blog.cjgammon.com/?p=392

Should be good enough to explain you how custom shaders work and how they're binded with all the uniforms that you need.

```
myTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world' + '.jpg');
myUniforms = [
myTex: { type: 't' /*texture type*/, value: myTex} ];

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
uniforms: myUniforms,
vertexShader: someMyVS,
fragmentShader: someMyFS});

// function onclick()
myUniforms.myTex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world_night' +
    '.jpg');
```

Hope this helps.